# What does "it" in "despite it being mandatory" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in a column of the newspaper *Times of India*:

> About 60% of vehicles driven on Indian roads are uninsured despite it being mandatory by law.

Although I get the meaning, I think the sentence needs a tweak syntactically. I think there should be

> "despite it being mandatory by law to insure"

otherwise it would suggest that "uninsured" is mandatory by law (although that wouldn't make much sense). Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it might be confusing for some people, the original sentence actually conveys the correct meaning, that "insurance" is actually mandatory.

The key is that "uninsured" is "not insured" associated with "despite". In a wicked kind of way, there is a double negation, which results in the correct meaning.

> "despite it being mandatory by law to insure"

That is indeed the intended meaning.

---

Additional to this, newspapers use [**headlinese**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), even in the normal text, not only in the headlines.